# Add a product description field to "Edit Selected Quote Line Items" page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lighting-web-component

My requirement is to display the product description field in "Edit Selected Quote Line Items" page which opens after you go to Quote object-->Related List Tab-->Quote Line Items List-->Add Product-->Select a Product-->Click next. The page which opens after this is the one in which I wish to add a new field (product description).

You can change the fields visible in this page via standard by going to page layout of Quote Line Item Object-->Quote Line Item Layout-->Edit Multi Line Layout-->Select which all fields you wish. Here the issue is that I do not know how to add fields from another object to this page. I understand since this functionality is not possible through admin and I have to proceed via development, but I do not know how to proceed.

I have shared some screenshots below to give you a wider understanding:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a cross object formula field from the Product Object field